# event SelectionChanged of listbox How to get textblock text value wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox, I have set a stackpanel and textblock in that. I want the last textblock's text because I have a set a value on last textbox text by using a converter.

The code posted below is tried by me and is not working

```
 private void listname_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string textt = (((sender as ListBox) as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBlock).Text; 

        //StackPanel sPanel = (sender as StackPanel) as StackPanel;
        //var tbxCollection = from tbx in sPanel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>()
        //                    where tbx.Name == "bl"
        //                    select tbx;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search your ContentControl ([ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) for Controls, then you can use [VisualTreeHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose.

The code below will help you to search for a specific Control(s) in DependencyObject - parent:

```
private static void SearchForControls<T>(DependencyObject parent, ref List<T> controlList) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int numberOfChildreen = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildreen; i++)
    {
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
       if (child is T) controlList.Add((T)child);
       else SearchForControls<T>(child, ref controlList);
    }
}
```

With this pice of code you can manage to complete your task like this:

```
private void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = (sender as ListBox).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
    List<StackPanel> controlList = new List<StackPanel>();
    SearchForControls<StackPanel>(item, ref controlList);
    string text = (controlList[0].Children[1] as TextBlock).Text;
}
```

In above code, in `controlList` you will get all `StackPanels` from you `SelectedItem` (accessed by `SelectedIndex`). For this example I assume that you have one `StackPanel` - hopefuly this will help you. Try to debug it and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better and easier to subscribe to textblocks Tap event instead

```
<DataTemplate>
<Textblock name="myTxtBlock" Tap="myTxtBlock_Tap"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

in code:

```
private void myTxtBlock_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
string text=(Sender as Textblock).Text;
}
```

Comment: Hello i want to on SelectionChanged event

Comment: @NishantChandwani then the answer posted by romasz would work perfect.